# How do I configure Eclipse's Java compiler to give an error for a non-UTF-8 character?

Tags: java, eclipse, utf-8

I have a Java file with a non-UTF-8 character in one of the comments. I've changed the file's character encoding to be UTF-8, but I don't get a compile error on that line. Is it possible to configure Eclipse's Java compiler to give me a compile error when it sees a non-UTF-8 character in a Java file?

Comment: When you set the character encoding to UTF-8, it will support both non-UTF-8 and UTF-8 characters. That's how it work.

Comment: What is this non UTF-8 character?

Comment: @ChuongPham: The issue is that someone is then trying to compile the file outside of Eclipse and running into an "unmappable character" error. Ideally, Eclipse would give us an error so we could fix the problem before shipping the file to someone else.

Comment: @DavidStruck: I don't understand "compile the file outside"? Do you mean someone used a text editor to edit the file and then save it outside of Eclipse? Well then that's a usage/team development issue, not programming! Eclipse, by default, does not care what data you have in a file, but if you tell it to save as UTF-8, it will. It will not do syntax checking for you wrt to this requirement.

Comment: @greg-449: The symbol is number 21 on http://www.alt-codes.net. The issue is someone is copying the text from somewhere else and pasting it into the Java file so we're not aware that it is there and subsequently causing a problem.

Comment: The 'section sign' is valid Unicode / UTF-8 (Unicode \u00A7, UTF-8 0xC2 0xA7)

Comment: @ChuongPham I believe someone is using the Ant javac task within Eclipse and getting the error. That said, your comment answers my question, so thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, David.